# Access Key, Value in Sass Map

Tags: css, sass

I have the following Sass Map:

```css
$font-scale: (
  0: (12, 16),
  1: (14, 16),
  2: (16, 20),
  3: (18, 20),
  4: (20, 24),
  5: (24, 28),
  6: (28, 32),
  7: (32, 32),
  8: (40, 40),
  9: (48, 48)
);
```

I want to generate font-size and line-height CSS variables for each item. The following is what I’m using to generate:

```css
:root {
 @each $name, $value in $font-scale {
   --font-size-scale-#{$name}: #{$value};
   --line-height-#{$name}: #{$value};
 }
}
```

The following is what I get:

```css
--font-size-scale-0: 12,16;
--line-height-0: 12,16;
--font-size-scale-1: 14,16;
--line-height-1: 14,16;
```

Instead, I want to get the following:

```
--font-size-scale-0: 12;
--line-height-0: 16;
--font-size-scale-1: 14;
--line-height-1: 16;
```

How can I access each value (`(12, 16)`) date and assign it to the variables?

Comment: The reason you are seeing the same value applied to all variables is because you did not include the [`nth()` module](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#nth) in your Sass code, which means it's just applying the first value it finds in the list each time. Using `nth` tells Sass to iterate through the map. It's like forgetting `i++` in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `nth` function, like this:

```
:root {
  @each $name, $value in $font-scale {
    --font-size-scale-#{$name}: #{nth($value,1)};
    --line-height-#{$name}: #{nth($value,2)};
  }
 }
```